# Check for valid path / dir

Tags: android

Users can determine a own directory to download their content to.
Now  i want implement to check if that entered directory can be created, is valid.
How do i do that?

Thx in advance.

```
public class DownloadLocationPickerDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener { 

final EditText path = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pick_location_dialog_path);

    public void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.pick_location_dialog_ok: {
            if (listener != null) {

                final EditText path = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pick_location_dialog_path);
                final String loc = path.getText().toString();
                listener.onDownloadLocationChanged(loc); 
            }
            dismiss();
        }
            break;
        case R.id.pick_location_dialog_cancel: {
            dismiss();
        }
            break;
        case R.id.pick_location_dialog_choose_path: {

            //
        }
            break;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the directory is on the SD Card:

```
File d = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dir_name");
```

Else:

```
File d = new File("/dir_name");
```

Then to check if it's a directory:

```
if(d.isDirectory()) { #do something }
```

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Hi Steve Olson,
Thx but 'Dir' doesn`t work, need to create seperate class.
How can i implement your code in mine?
Thx again.

Comment: Hi Steve a question is there any way i can avoid that the user creates directories like /storage/emulated/0/home///
It should be a valid one like /storage/emulated/0/home/
Thx again

Comment: Lol sorry Bjorn I'm an idiot. It should be "File" instead of "Dir", looks like I'm too tired as well